# Code/Tool to extract metadata from malicious PDFs

Tags: linux, python, pdf

I am studying features of malicious PDFs. I have am using a Python wrapper of pdfinfo to extract some features like file size and page size of the code. This is the wrapper part of the code.

```
 def pdfinf(infile):
   cmd = '/usr/bin/pdfinfo'
   if not osp.exists(cmd):
       raise RuntimeError('System command not found: %s' % cmd)
   if not osp.exists(infile):
       raise RuntimeError('Provided input file not found: %s' % infile)

   def _extract(row):
       """Extracts the right hand value from a : delimited row"""
       return row.split(':', 1)[1].strip()

   output = {}

   labels = ['Title', 'Author', 'Creator', 'Producer', 'CreationDate',
              'ModDate', 'Tagged', 'Pages', 'Encrypted', 'Page size',
              'File size', 'Optimized', 'PDF version']

   cmd_output = subprocess.check_output([cmd, infile])
   for line in cmd_output.splitlines():
       for label in labels:
           if label in line:
               output[label] = _extract(line)
   return output

la = lb = 0

for files in malware_files:
    path = "/home/hima/Downloads/data/mpdfs/" + files
    output = pdfinf(path)
    value = output['File size']
    value = value[:-6]
    lb += float(value)
```

However, I keep getting errors like these.

```
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error (6689): Missing 'endstream' or incorrect stream length
Syntax Error (15795): Missing 'endstream' or incorrect stream length
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 67, in <module>
    output = pdfinf(path)
  File "code.py", line 50, in pdfinf
    cmd_output = subprocess.check_output([cmd, infile])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/pdfinfo', '/home/hima/Downloads/data/mpdfs/c9954f5f3fbfb3b150abe208c763d942043bfc0f.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

How can I extract these features if the code stops running at a malicious file? I want to analyze these features as I think that if will be able find a relation. Is there an alternative to pdfinfo that I can call using shell or using a wrapper in Python?

Comment: You want a PDF parser that parses malformed PDF?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, and then it should give me some metadata

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to inspect broken PDF files is just to open them in an editor that can deal with large files (I use emacs). First try this with a good PDF files. You'll see the object structure of the PDF file, but some or all content streams will be compressed. You'll also be able to see this way what the "malicious" PDF is doing to confuse your parser, and you should be able to correct the parser accordingly. (Without knowing what the "malicious" PDF does, we can't do that for you, obviously).

You can also use `mutool clean -d` to decompress the streams, but `mutool` may or may not be confused by what your broken PDF does. Again, try this first on a valid PDF.

Comment: I find it slightly odd that a "malicious PDF" would want to _confuse_ a parser... If parsers can't parse it, what's the point of being malicious?

Comment: It's less a matter of what it "wants", but what happens. If whoever wrote the broken PDF thought he could confuse *some* parsers didn't try *your* parser, then *your* parser may very well become confused ... In any case, that's not important. Just have a look at what goes wrong.